# Shorter way to acces object id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var locations = [
[{id: 1, lat: 51.52376322544537, lng: 5.13785702262885, content: 'Title A'}],
[{id: 2, lat: 51.52358632767757, lng: 5.137921395645208, content: 'Title B'}],
[{id: 3, lat: 51.52343946863126, lng: 5.138093057022161, content: 'Title C'}],
];
```

I want to access the id's now i do it like this:

```
if (id === 7 || id === 13 || id === 15 || id === 16) {
        marker.setIcon(icon4);
    }
```

I thought this was a shorter way:

```
if (id.toString().indexOf(['7','13','15','16'] > -1)) {
        }
```

But this is not working can somebody help me out on this, it is frustrating me because i don't like that code i use.

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in quote`'` ?

Comment: you can use indexOf, in array. It depends of the version of your navigator, search it into mdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to

```
if ([7,13,15,16].indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
        marker.setIcon(icon4);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch instead of if

```
switch(id)
{
case 7:
case 13:
case 15:
case 16:
marker.setIcon(icon4);
break;
}
```

in future if any new id is added it is easy to add only one case.
I hope it will useful.